# How much thrust is available from the Allison T-56-A-15 engine?

Tags: engine

What is the thrust availability per engine in Lockheed C130H?
The engines are Allison T-56-A-15 (SHP=4100, SFC=0.5)
Propellers = NP2000 eight Bladed(Prop Efficiency if assumed to be 90% constant at all speeds)
SHP - Shaft Horse Power

Comment: @mins That answer provides the KW output for the engine, which isn't the same as the thrust it provides which is entirely dependent on the propeller efficiency. The thrust should be measured in newtons, kg-f, or lb-f.

Comment: @RonBeyer: That's right, it's the power of the turboprop, the thrust developed by the propeller with this input power [will depends on the speed](http://forums.jetcareers.com/threads/horsepower-to-thrust-conversion.43771/), and the propeller efficiency (which is not constant over the speed range ➭ `Fn = SHP × 375 × efficiency / speed in MPH`).

Comment: What is the "speed" in your equation? The speed of the aircraft? The formula breaks down at zero speed (obviously), and speeds approaching zero can't have infinite thrust. Is the "speed" value a cruise speed? At least in another field (marine) we measure thrust using bollard pull techniques, which is akin to chaining the boat to the dock and increasing power until the thrust produced maxes out...

Comment: @mins The 'speed' in the equation, is it cruise speed?

Comment: @Evilz: Yes, it is.

Comment: @RonBeyer: At 0 speed, there is no work, equivalent thrust is null too except the core thrust that may be 15% of the total, and that isn't taken into account here. I think this formula is an approximation for comparison turbojet vs propeller purpose. See [more](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/propulsion/q0195.shtml).

Comment: @mins Are the effects due to propeller geometry(dimensions, twist, no. of blades etc.) included in the propeller efficiency? If no, then what role do they play in the availability of thrust?

Comment: @Evilz: I think you should ask a separate question, as this is not a forum site (see [Tour](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour), or chat in a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)). Efficiency takes all that into account, but remember that efficiency varies with speed and density, etc, and also blade pitch (if pitch is variable). Another issue is that you need to know how much horsepower is produced by the engine when the a/c cruises (this is likely not the maximum hp).

Comment: @mins Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Your question is hard to follow. You may edit it with new lines when suited, space befor opening paranthesis, where you find those figure, the signification of those figures (a.g. what does SHP means?),...

Answer (score 2):

From Raymer's "Conceptual Aircraft Design", page 327, equation 13.15:

$$ \eta_p = \frac{TV}{P}$$

Where:

- $\eta_P$ is the propeller efficiency
- $T$ is the Thrust [kN]
- $V$ is the True Airspeed [m/s]
- $P$ is the engine power [kW]

Reverting the formula you get that the Thrust per engine is given by:

$$ T  = \frac{P \eta_p}{V}$$